# Parsing xml with multi childs using jsoup

Tags: java, android, xml, jsoup

I have an xml file that looks as follows - [link](https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo_library/libweb/webservices/rest/primo-explore/v1/pnxs/xml/L/NNL_ALEPH21191127040005171?vid=NLI&lang=iw_IL&search_scope=Local&adaptor=Local%20Search%20Engine&inst=NNL&showPnx=true&jwtAsParam=eyJraWQiOiJwcmltb0V4cGxvcmVQcml2YXRlS2V5LU5OTCIsImFsZyI6IkVTMjU2In0.eyJpc3MiOiJQcmltbyIsImp0aSI6IiIsImV4cCI6MTYwNDc2NDk2OSwiaWF0IjoxNjA0Njc4NTY5LCJ1c2VyIjoiYW5vbnltb3VzLTExMDZfMTYwMjQ5IiwidXNlck5hbWUiOm51bGwsInVzZXJHcm91cCI6IkdVRVNUIiwiYm9yR3JvdXBJZCI6bnVsbCwidWJpZCI6bnVsbCwiaW5zdGl0dXRpb24iOiJOTkwiLCJ2aWV3SW5zdGl0dXRpb25Db2RlIjoiTk5MIiwiaXAiOiI3OS4xODMuMTkyLjE1OSIsInBkc1JlbW90ZUluc3QiOm51bGwsIm9uQ2FtcHVzIjoiZmFsc2UiLCJsYW5ndWFnZSI6Iml3X0lMIiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25Qcm9maWxlIjoiIiwidmlld0lkIjoiTkxJIiwiaWxzQXBpSWQiOm51bGwsInNhbWxTZXNzaW9uSW5kZXgiOiIifQ.etSefGcY4oEvTaNTE4LlF-gJobvpoZQwSy6ClDlaOB3E5CSeYqSlFnJCJQ3ALjRbPHWUDZL8AuaRB9tBmt4HRA).

I would like to get the title from it.

In order to do so, I did the following:

```
Document bookDoc = Jsoup.connect( url ).parser( Parser.xmlParser() ).get();
Node node  = bookDoc.childNode( 2 ).childNode( 3 ).childNode( 3 );
```

This returns me this:

[image]

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Isnt there any simpler way to get this title instead of using all of these childNodes? My worry is that in some result the title wont exactly be at childNode(3) and all my code wont work.
2. How do I eventually get this title? Im stuck at this point and cant get the string of the title.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use selectors to access elements. Here you want to select by tag name. Two ways to get the element you want:

```
String title1 = bookDoc.select("record>display>title").text();
String title2 = bookDoc.selectFirst("record").selectFirst("display").selectFirst("title").text();
```

If you want to select more complicated things read:
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax
But you probably won't need them for parsing this XML.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to under it mate